# Statically linked Haskell program in Docker

Tags: haskell, docker

I'm trying to build a statically linked binary from Haskell source code, and copy this binary to a minimal Docker image so that my production image is as small as possible.

As a test case I'm using a hello world program:

```
main = print "Hello world"
```

The `test.cabal` file is the default generated by `cabal init`, except that I added

```
ghc-options: -static -optc-static -optl-static -optl-threaded
```

To build I run

```
$ docker run -it -v $(pwd):/src haskell:7.10 /bin/bash
# cd src
# cabal build
```

The build gives the following error:

```
opt/ghc/7.10.1/lib/ghc-7.10.1/rts/libHSrts.a(Linker.o): In function `internal_dlopen': (.text+0x727): warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
```

From what I understood, this means that I need to make sure I have the correct version of glibc in order to be able to execute the binary. Executing the binary works fine in the same container:

```
# ./dist/build/test/test
"Hello world"
```

It's also statically linked as expected:

```
# ldd ./dist/build/test/test
not a dynamic executable
```

To create my minimal image, I create a Dockerfile (the `libc.so.6` file is copied from the `haskell:7.10` image):

```
FROM scratch
ADD dist/build/test/test /test
ADD libc.so.6 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
CMD ["/test"]
```

This does not work when I try to build and run it

```
$ docker build -t test .
$ docker run -it test
test: out of memory (requested 1048576 bytes)
```

I tried the same thing starting from a `busybox` image (without adding `libc.so.6`) but this did not work either. Adding it to a `ubuntu:14.04` did work (this is probably because `haskell:7.10` is based on this image).

I tried running `strace` on the command, but was not able to make much sense of it. The `strace` output is here: http://pastebin.com/SNHT14Z9

Can I make this work from `scratch`? Or is this impossible due to the 'dlopen' issue?

Comment: You're probably interested in [this article](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2015/05/haskell-web-server-in-5mb).

Comment: That article is actually the reason I decided to try my hand at recreating the same thing but using a static binary. I did try to run my static binary starting from `dysinger/haskell-scratch`, but this results in error code 139.

Comment: Wasn't sure about this, since you've used `scratch`, not `haskell-scratch` as mentioned in the article, see https://github.com/snoyberg/haskell-scratch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You encountered a feature of GHC runtime system. Even the application is static, it needs some auxiliary files, locale files are one of them.

See https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7695 and https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10298

As you can see, that will be fixed in 7.10.2 (which at the moment is right behind the corner).

https://github.com/snoyberg/haskell-scratch image lists hopefully all files you need in the minimal container.

Comment: I tried again with the `haskell-scratch` image, but this time with `snoyberg/haskell-scratch`. That did the trick. When 7.10.2 is out I'll try again and see if I can really start from `scratch` then. Thanks!

Comment: This is more a feature of iconv than of GHC (the only thing special about GHC is that its base package uses iconv extensively),